# Getting shadows to work in Three.js custom shader

Tags: three.js, shader, shadows

I'm trying to get shadows to work in a custom shader in Three.js. I've tried to add these into my codes:

In uniforms:

```
THREE.UniformsLib["shadowmap"]
```

In the fragment shader:

```
THREE.ShaderChunk["shadowmap_pars_fragment"]
THREE.ShaderChunk["shadowmap_fragment"]
```

In the vertex shader:

```
THREE.ShaderChunk["shadowmap_pars_vertex"]
THREE.ShaderChunk["shadowmap_vertex"]
```

which works. The object can receive shadows.

However, it cannot cast shadows. Does anyone know what other bits of codes are needed?

Answer (score -4):

I believe that you need to mark each object as casting and receiving shadows

I think its just

```
obj.castShadow = true;
obj.recieveShadow = true;
```