# ThreeJS: Adding shadows to custom shaders r75

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

In the past it was possible to incorporate the shadow calculations in custom shaders as described [here](http://blog.edankwan.com/post/three-js-advanced-tips-shadow) and summed up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18962155/getting-shadows-to-work-in-three-js-custom-shader).

With r75, the lighting and shadow systems seem to have been merged, changing this. I attempted to work my way through the source to to understand but the abstraction/modules are a little tricky to follow.

I've distilled my shaders down to what I have so far:

Vertex:

```
#chunk(shadowmap_pars_vertex);

void main() {
    vec4 worldPosition = modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;

    #chunk(shadowmap_vertex);
}
```

Fragment

```
#chunk(common);
#chunk(lights_pars);
#chunk(shadowmap_pars_fragment);

void main() {

//#if ( NUM_DIR_LIGHTS > 0 )

    IncidentLight directLight;
    DirectionalLight directionalLight;

    float shadowValue = 1.0;

    for ( int i = 0; i < NUM_DIR_LIGHTS; i ++ ) {

        directionalLight = directionalLights[ i ];

        shadowValue = getShadow( directionalShadowMap[ i ], directionalLight.shadowMapSize, directionalLight.shadowBias, directionalLight.shadowRadius, vDirectionalShadowCoord[ i ] );
    }

//#endif

    gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(shadowValue), 1.0);
}
```

I pulled the directional light loop from the [lights_template chunk](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk/lights_template.glsl). Unfortunately, `shadowValue` always seems to return 1.0, but it does work and the shader renders correctly otherwise.

My JS has the appropriate `castShadow` and `receiveShadow` set. Other meshes using Phong render shadows correctly.

Thanks so much in advance.

**Edit:**
Adding `material.lights = true;` to the `ShaderMaterial` makes *something* appear, however the value of `shadowValue` in the fragment shader is clearly incorrect on the side of the sphere facing away from the light. Screenshots attached.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Sorry! I just saw this. My solution was to use `dot(lightPosition, normal)` basically if the dot product returned a number very close to 0 it is on the backside of the geometry and would therefore be in shadow anyway.

The exact code which goes in the fragment shader above is: 
`shadowValue += (1.0 - step(0.002, dot(directionalLight.direction, vNormal))) * clamp(length(vNormal), 0.0, 1.0);`

I'm not sure if this will work for every scenario, but it's worked for me so far.

@cjonasw

Comment: http://blog.edankwan.com/post/three-js-advanced-tips-shadow